# Google Play reject my wear os companion app with crashed when launch on phone

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-3.0

Can anyone help me clarify what does "Your application crashed when launch on phone" means for a wear os companion app? I tested my wear os app on API 28 and API 30, everything works fine. It is just an incremental update, but it keeps getting rejected recently by google play.

Comment: I'm not certain it will show up, but is there any thing in "Crashes and ANRs" in the Play Store Console?

Comment: @YuriSchimke Thanks for your kindly constant support. Please see the detail info to this case (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73332049/3569768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To post an update on this issue, long story short. For my android app with wear os companion, It was my android apps' problem with the release build using `minification` and `shrinkResources` with `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` following the android doc. The `proguard-android-optimize` renamed a couple of class names so that the start of explicit intent crash on all android devices.

The unfortunate things are:

- I didn't test the release build from playstore manually. (all on me, now I am testing with play internal test)
- All apps with wear os companion component on play store are called wear os apps, which gives a lot of confusion
- My release build with code minification problem had passed all prelaunch report tests on google play initially, and I didn't see any `crash` report on google play. (I don't know why this is possible)
- I managed to found out this issue totally by accident and my root cause might not be applicable for all other apps with the same reject text.

Answer (score 0):

You have any update on this?
Same thing just happened to me, got rejected on an incremental update. I then tried preventing the installation on a phone like this:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.wearable" android:required="true" />
```

Then it got rejected because they couldn't install it on a phone anymore

Comment: Is your wear app a standalone? Do you have the meta-data tag `com.google.android.wearable.standalone` set for `true`, my wear app is a companion app, which has an android app too. Playstore just called my both apps `wear app`. Please see more details to my case (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73332049/3569768)